# Extension of locally convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am looking for a reference or a result about the extension of locally convex increasing functions in a neighborhood of $0$ by a strictly convex and increasing functions in $(0, \infty)$.

---

A function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is said to be ***locally convex*** in a neighborhood of $0$ if and only if, $\exists \, \beta > 0$ such that function $g$ is convex where $g=\left\{(x, f(x)): -\beta \leq x \leq +\beta \, \right\}$

---

Let $R \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, a function $f : R\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be ***convex*** if $\forall x, y, z\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $x < y < z$, then
$$f(y) <  (y - x) \dfrac{(f(z) - f(x))}{z - x}.$$

Comment: What's a "locally convex" increasing function?

Comment: I think that I have made an error, if a function is convex then it is increasing. thank you for the hint.

Comment: If a differentiable function is convex, then the **derivative** is increasing. Not every convex function is increasing. If you're just interested in convex increasing functions, then such an extension will exist if and only if the right-hand derivative at $0$ (extending $f$ continuously to $0$; it can always be done given the hypotheses) is strictly positive. I could try proving that if you want?

Comment: Thank you sir, yes I'm looking for a proof. I will be grateful for you sir.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried a few times to write an answer, but it ends up blowing up out of proportion (primarily because I don't know what I can assume you know). What I can give you is a formula for the extension, which you can try to prove if you want. Let $D^+f(0)$ be the right derivative at $0$ (once continuously extended to $0$) and assume it is positive. Then let$$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if } x \ge 0 \\ D^+f(0)(e^x - 1) + f(0) & \text{if }x < 0.\end{cases}$$This $g$ satisfies what you want.

Comment: thank you sir, but i still don't see the necessity of the existence of the right derivative at the point 0.

Comment: Well, the first thing to note is that, once you extend $f$ to $0$, that $f$ is still convex on $[0,\infty)$. The reason is, the quantity$$\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)-f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)$$is non-negative for all $x, y > 0$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, so this continuous function of $x, y, \lambda$ is non-negative on the closure of the domain, which includes where $x, y = 0$.

Comment: Second, you can then use the three slope lemma, also known as the chordal slope lemma (see [this pdf](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/6-6.pdf)), to establish the existence of a right derivative. Using the lemma, we know for $0<h_1<h_2$,$$\frac{f(0+h_1)-f(0)}{h_1}\le\frac{f(0+h_2)-f(0)}{h_2},$$which means that $\frac{f(0 + h)-f(0)}{h}$ is monotone decreasing as $h\to0^+$. We also know it's bounded below by $0$, as $f$ is assumed to be increasing near $0$. So, the limit must exist, by the monotone convergence theorem. The question is, is it $0$ or is it strictly positive?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bendit for all you answers and supports. Actually, the problem come from this paper: onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mma.4604. Actually, the author assumes in (2.2) the existence of $H$ such that $H(0)=H′(0)=0.$ I don't see really from where the assumption $H′(0)=0$ comes. Maybe it is used to extend $H$ on $(0,∞)$ (See 2.10). He doesn't need to assume that $H'(0)$ is positive.

Comment: I think I may have fundamentally misunderstood your question. I thought your function was defined on $(0, \infty)$, and you wished to extend it to $\Bbb{R}$. By the looks of the paper, the function is defined on some $(0, r]$, and needs to be extended to $(0, \infty)$. That being the case, the derivative at $0$ is immaterial. As for why $H'(0) = 0$ is enforced, I don't know without properly reading the paper. Maybe it is to ensure that $H_1(t)$ is a sensible, finite improper integral?

Comment: I think that the integral is already improper with the  assumption $H(0)=0$, I looked for a justification for this assumption but I didn't find any interpretation! what do you think?.

Comment: The integral wouldn't necessarily be improper, since it considers only $\frac{1}{H'}$, not $\frac{1}{H}$. But, being improper is not the point; the point is that $H'(0) = 0$ would be necessary so that the integrand $\frac{1}{sH'(s)}$ doesn't look like $\frac{1}{H'(0)s}$, which produces a divergent integral. Beyond this, I really don't know. I'm not invested enough to try to read the entirety of the paper to figure out specifically why $H'(0) = 0$ is important.

Comment: Actually the goal  is to make the integral $\int \frac{1}{sH'(s)}$ improper, it is the case when $H'(0) \neq 0$ since $\int 1/s$ diverges. I don't see another reason.

Comment: I think we're saying more or less the same thing here.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible in general. Consider
$$
f(x) = \max( - \sqrt{1-x}, - \sqrt{1+x}).
$$
It is convex on $[-1,1]$, has infinite slope at $x=\pm 1$, so cannot be extended to a convex function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.